# PHP data formation with array with some existing value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Suppose I have some value like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [amount] => 4000.00
            [monthyear] => 2018-02
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [amount] => 5000.00
            [monthyear] => 2018-01
        )
)
```

I want to generate some value like this

```
[5000,4000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I used foreach loop and for loop but I can't understand how to do this, it's actually generating a sum of balance report by month.

Is it possible to generate this value via CodeIgniter?

My query for the above output is:

```
$this->cm->select_sum = "amount";
$this->cm->select = "DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') as monthyear";
$this->cm->table_name = "personal_balance";
$this->cm->where = array("DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y')" => date('Y'));
$this->cm->group_by = "DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m')";
$balance = $this->cm->get();
```

Comment: First you need to be able to successfully create a new array `[5000, 4000]` by iterating over the existing. Then you can [use array_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) to extend the new array with '0's to the desired length.

Comment: The report will be month based . this is not important to placed the values at the very first . those values can be anywhere .

Comment: Show us the loops you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that do the job I guess.

```
$monthBalance = [];
foreach($balance as $entry){
    $month = intval(substr($entry['monthyear']),6,7));
    $monthBalance[$month] = $entry;
}
//so there is [1=>obj(), 2=>obj(), 5=>obj] in it


$value = [];
for($m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++) {

    //if the balance month currently exists in the DB results
    if( isset($monthBalance[$m]) ){

       $value[] = $monthBalance[$m]->amount;

    } else {

       $value[] = 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: this not gonna work, cause if there was 3 value for month 1,2 and 5 the output for this code will be [1,2,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], But i need to get output like this [1,2,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,], Hope You Understand.

Comment: Oh, okey, I try to fixe it ^^